# Multiple template parameter inheritance c++

Tags: c++, templates

I want to implement a BinaryIndexedTree template class that inherits from a BinaryTree class.  My BinaryTree class is a template with two parameters and and an nested class like this:

**BinaryTree:**

```
#pragma once
#include <queue>
#include "InternalBinaryTreeNode.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T, class IBTN = InternalBinaryTreeNode<T>>
class BinaryTree{
public:

    class BinaryTreeNode
    {
    public:
        virtual ~BinaryTreeNode(void){}
        //...

    protected:
        friend class    BinaryTree<T>;

        BinaryTreeNode(IBTN* node){
            mActualNode = node;
        }

        IBTN    *mActualNode;
    };

private:
    IBTN*   mRevInEnd;
    IBTN*   mRevPostEnd;
    IBTN*   mInEnd;
    IBTN*   mRevPreEnd;
    IBTN*   mPreEnd;
    IBTN*   mPostEnd;
    int     mNodeDisplayWidth;

public:
    BinaryTree(void)
    {
        mNodeDisplayWidth = 6;
        mRevInEnd   = new IBTN();
        mRevPostEnd = new IBTN();
        mInEnd      = new IBTN();
        mRevPreEnd  = mInEnd;
        mPreEnd     = new IBTN();
        mPostEnd    = mPreEnd;

        mRevPostEnd->mLeftChild  = 0;
        mRevPostEnd->mRightChild = 0;
        mRevPostEnd->mParent     = mRevInEnd;

        mRevInEnd->mLeftChild  = mRevPostEnd;
        mRevInEnd->mRightChild = mInEnd;
        mRevInEnd->mParent     = 0;

        mInEnd->mLeftChild  = 0;
        mInEnd->mRightChild = mPreEnd;
        mInEnd->mParent     = mRevInEnd;

        mPreEnd->mLeftChild  = 0;
        mPreEnd->mRightChild = 0;
        mPreEnd->mParent     = mInEnd;
    }


    virtual ~BinaryTree(void){
        //...
    }

};
```

IBTN(InternalBinaryTreeNode) is my inner node that the user doesn't need to work with, and I inherit InternalIndexedBinaryTreeNode from IBTN and add an `int` field :

**InternalBinaryTreeNode:**

```
#pragma once
template <class T, class IBTN>
class BinaryTree;

template <class T>
class InternalBinaryTreeNode
{
public:
    InternalBinaryTreeNode(void)
    {
        mLeftChild = 0;
        mRightChild = 0;
    }

    virtual ~InternalBinaryTreeNode(void)
    {
    }

    friend class BinaryTree<T, InternalBinaryTreeNode<T>>;

protected:
    T                           mData;
    InternalBinaryTreeNode<T>*  mParent;
    InternalBinaryTreeNode<T>*  mLeftChild;
    InternalBinaryTreeNode<T>*  mRightChild;
    // used for drawing
    int                         mPosition; // Position in the level of tree
};
```

and this is my **InternalIndexedBinaryTreeNode**:

```
#include "InternalBinaryTreeNode.h"

template<class T>
class InternalIndexedBinaryTreeNode:public InternalBinaryTreeNode<T>{

public:
    InternalIndexedBinaryTreeNode(){
        leftSize=0;
    }

    ~InternalIndexedBinaryTreeNode(){
    }

    virtual int getLeftSize(){
        return leftSize;
    }
    friend class IndexedBinaryTree<T,InternalIndexedBinaryTreeNode<T>>;
protected:
    int leftSize;
};
```

and when I implement my IndexedBinaryTreeNode like this:

```
#include "BinaryTree.h"
#include "InternalIndexedBinaryTreeNode.h"

template<class T,class IBTN = InternalIndexedBinaryTreeNode<T>>
class IndexedBinaryTree:public BinaryTree<T,IBTN>{

public:
    IndexedBinaryTree(){

    }

public:
    class BinaryIndexedTreeNode:public BinaryTree<T,IBTN>::BinaryTreeNode{
        friend class IndexedBinaryTree<T,InternalIndexedBinaryTreeNode<T>>;

    };
};
```

I get this error:

> 1 error C2059: syntax error : '<' internalindexedbinarytreenode.h Line19
>
> 2 error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>   internalindexedbinarytreenode.h Line 19
>
> 3 error C2989: 'IndexedBinaryTree' : class template has already been
>   declared as a non-class template indexedbinarytree.h Line24
>
> 4 error C3857:'IndexedBinaryTree': multiple template parameter lists
>   are not allowed indexedbinarytree.h Line 5

I've been struggling with this for two weeks but I've failed!

Comment: For one, the line `friend class IndexedBinaryTree<T,InternalIndexedBinaryTreeNode<T>;` in your last code snippet has a missing closing `>`.  As an aside, you might benefit by using shorter names in your code.  "Descriptive" doesn't necessarily mean long.

Comment: @MaxBozzi thank you but its just a homework for D S student and they dont need to work with classes they just fill 2 function in BinaryIndexedTree...but you R right :)